# Backend Сервер для Аndroid-приложений

Tags: android, сервер

Нужно построить сервер для обработки запросов с Аndroid-приложений.
Запрос состоит из текста. Сервер должен парсировать текст и в соответствии с базой данных вернуть ответ.

На чем лучше писать сервер? Есть ли туториалы на эту тему?

Comment: php, а можно parse.com попробовать

Comment: Андроид тут ни при чем. Ничего особенного сервер, с которым работают Андроид-приложения, не содержит. Поэтому ваш вопрос должен звучать как "Как написать backend сервер?"

Comment: @Gorets parse.com загнулся

Comment: @Andrey знаю, но ты тоже во время, через 2 года после комментария

Answer (score 1):

ну раз пишите под Андроид то Java наверное знаете. Тогда наверное нужно глянуть в сторону J2EE. Ну а вообще все зависит от постановки. Может быть стоит глянуть в сторону каких то облаков. или сервер и база настолько приватные что только свой писать. а может вообще использовать что-то типа parse.com залить туда данные и пользоваться ими вообще без бекенда (ну всмысле без самописного). или на Питоне что-нибудь забацать

Answer (score 0):

Погуглите REST API, выберите язык, который нравится и напишите серверную часть. С андроид клиента можно доступаться через Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Если сервер ограничивается парсингом строки и бд - пишите на php. Уровень входа в язык нулевой, хостинги копеечные. Java EE это хорошо, но, лично я думаю, на нее все же больше ресурсов уйдет, как временных так и денежных